# Do I have to use this cast when getting doubleValue from a dictionary member?

Tags: objective-c

```
((NSString *)result[@"location"][@"lat"]).doubleValue
```

Or is there a shortened notation?

Basically I want to cast some stuff to NSString and get some property. Without the bracket it doesn't work though.

I think there should be a more "elegant" notation. If so, what is it, and can that be explained? What's the priority, etc.

Comment: you can call method instead of property:
[(NSString *)result[@"location"][@"lat"] doubleValue]

Comment: Please turn that into an answer. There is no more elegant way isn't it?

Comment: I already suspected that actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's shorter to do it this way:

```
[result[@"location"][@"lat"] doubleValue]
```

because the return type of `result[@"location"][@"lat"]` is `id`, and you can send any message to an `id` without a complaint from the compiler.  (Of course, the object has to understand the message at run time or you'll get a fatal exception.)